# Can I source the list items of a dropdown box from an excel sheet in Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

I have a long list of codes that change monthly, that I would like to include in my app as a dropdown. However, I do not know how to import that list into Power Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can keep the Excel online from OneDrive, then change the content every month.

So now create a connection to the OneDrive file, load the excel content into collections using `ClearCollect(YourCollectionNameHere,Table1)` on App start.

Then bind the `Table1` to your dropdown control values. [Reference](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/import-excel-to-a-powerapps-collection/td-p/421570)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the list in *any* data source supported by PowerApps and pull it in `OnStart` of the application. Create a [collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-data-sources) using something like `ClearCollect(colName, Filter(dataSource, condition = value))`. Be sure to use a delegable data source if more than 2000 values are returned.

**Some Data Source Ideas**: (there are something like [200 available out-of-the box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connector-reference/connector-reference-powerapps-connectors)!)

- Excel (manually uploaded and app republished)
- Excel Online + OneDrive
- Sharepoint list
- Azure SQL table
- On-prem database table + OnPrem Data Gateway
- REST endpoint + custom connector

You could even use Flow to pull the table out of the text of an email body!

The sky is the limit in regards to extensibility. The question usually comes down to [premium licensing costs](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/). Do you want to pay for a better data source?